# Sending update request to update a profile getting undefined in server side

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, sequelize.js, react-hooks

I am sending an axios put request to update Profile details. I have also got a non editable email field, in this case how can I send email id along with `Axios.put(..` request.

While setting a breakpoint in server side, I could see the `edited field` values are available in `req.body`

I have grab the email as below, but not sure how to send along with updateProfile:

`const userEmail = document.getElementsByName('email').value;`

`server.js`

```
app.put('/service/profile', async (req, res, next) => {

  try {
    const userEmail = req.body.userEmail;
    var selector = { 
      where: { email: userEmail }
    };
    const updatePlayer = await UserModel.update(req.body, selector);
    console.log("Server side update method log:" + updatePlayer);
    res.status(200).json({ success: true });
  } catch (err) {
    //res.status(500).json({ message: e.message })
    return next(err);
  }

});
```

`Profile.js`

```
const [playerProfile, setPlayerProfile] = useState([]);
const [updateProfile, setUpdateProfile] = useState({ _id: '', photo: '', name: '', email: '', phonenumber: '', position: '', password: '' })

const handleChange = (e, id) => {
    e.persist();
    let itemIndex;
    const targetPlayer = playerProfile.find((player, index) => {
      console.log({ player, id, index });
      itemIndex = index; 
      return player.id === id;
    });

    console.log({ targetPlayer, id, e });

    const editedTarget = {
      ...targetPlayer,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    };
    const tempPlayers = Array.from(playerProfile);
    tempPlayers[itemIndex] = editedTarget;
    setPlayerProfile(tempPlayers);
    setUpdateProfile({ ...updateProfile, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const onSubmit = () => {
    setDisabled(disabled);
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
    const userEmail = document.getElementsByName('email').value;
    const res = await Axios.put('http://localhost:8000/service/profile', updateProfile, userEmail);
        console.log("Front End update message:" + res.data.success);
        if (res.data.success) {
          setIsSent(true);
          history.push('/')
        }
        else {
          console.log(res.data.message);
          setHelperText(res.data.message);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        setHelperText(e.response.data.message);
      }
    }
    fetchData();
  }


return (
    <div className="register_wrapper">
      <div className="register_player_column_layout_one">
        <div className="register_player_Twocolumn_layout_two">
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="myForm">
            {
              playerProfile.map(({ id, photo, name, email, phonenumber, position, privilege, password }) => (
                <div key={id}>
                  <div className="fillContentDiv formElement">
                    <label>
                      <input className="inputRequest formContentElement" name="name" type="text" value={name} 
                      onChange={e => handleChange(e, id)}
                      maxLength={30}
                      ref={register({
                        required: "Full name is required", 
                        pattern: {
                          value: /^[a-zA-Z\s]{3,30}$/,
                          message: "Full name should have minimum of 3 letters"
                        }
                      })}
                      />
                      <span className="registerErrorTextFormat">{errors.name && errors.name.message}</span>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                      <input className="inputRequest formContentElement" name="email" type="text" value={email} 
                      onChange={e => handleChange(e, id)}
                      disabled={disabled}
                      />
                    </label>
                    <label>
                      <input className="inputRequest formContentElement" name="phonenumber" type="text" value={phonenumber} 
                      onChange={e => handleChange(e, id)}
                      maxLength={11}
                      ref={register({
                        required: "Phone number is required",
                        pattern: {
                          value: /^[0-9\b]+$/,
                          message: "Invalid phone number"
                        }
                       })}
                      />
                      <span className="registerErrorTextFormat">{errors.phonenumber && errors.phonenumber.message}</span>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                      <input className="inputRequest formContentElement" name="position" type="text" value={position} onChange={e => handleChange(e, id)}/>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                      <div className="select" >
                        <select name="privilege" id="select" value={privilege} onChange={e => handleChange(e, id)}>
                          <option value="player">PLAYER</option>
                          {/*<option value="admin">ADMIN</option>*/}
                        </select>
                      </div>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                      <input className="inputRequest formContentElement" name="password" type="password" value={password} 
                      onChange={e => handleChange(e, id)}
                      minLength={4}
                      maxLength={30}
                      ref={register({
                      required: "Password is required",
                      pattern: {
                        value: /^(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z\d]+$/,
                        message: "Password begin with a letter and includes number !"
                      }
                      })}
                      />
                      <span className="registerErrorTextFormat">{errors.password && errors.password.message}</span>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <label>
                    <span className="profileValidationText">{helperText}</span>
                  </label>
                  <div className="submitButtonDiv formElement">
                    <button type="submit" className="submitButton">Save</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))
            }
          </form>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

after getting `app` from `express()`
write

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}))
```